# Facebook error on tab application with fbgraph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am trying to ask for extended permissions on a Facebook tab application with fbgraph gem on ROR3.

The error message given is:

```js
{
       "error": {
          "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
          "type": "OAuthException"
       }
    }
```

I was trying with localhost. I thought that the problem was with localhost, so I uploaded my site to a server and then I configured the Facebook app. However, this threw this error message.

I configured on my application: Basic info, Page tab info and in advanced tab I wrote "deauthorize callback url".

The generated URL is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffbpromo.testenvironment.com.ar%2Fauthorize&response_type=code&scope=email+read_stream+offline_access+manage_pages+user_about_me
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem was my configuration. However, Facebook redirects out of tab application.

How could I configure my application if I want to request permissions without exiting out of my tab application?

My page is allocated for example in http://example.com/facebook_callback. How could it be redirected to http://www.facebook_com/app_id/callback_url (i.e., redirect 'inside' tab application)?

Comment: "Sorry, the problem was my configuration." That's simply Not an Answer. Please replace this with a real answer. The rest of this "answer" is actually a separate question, and should be asked as such.